# How to implement search filter to an existing list in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Below is my HTML

```
<ul style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled" xmlns:list-style-type="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <li *ngFor="let t of acquirer_response | keys">
    <ul class="list-unstyled"  class="list-group" >
      <li *ngFor="let b of t.value | keys ">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" style ="list-style-type: none" >
          <strong (click)="t.isCollapsedContent =!t.isCollapsedContent" (click)=" toggleSign(sign)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign"></span> {{b.key}}</strong>
          <div *ngIf="t.isCollapsedContent">
            <li *ngFor="let c of b.value | keys ">
              <div *ngIf="c.key == 'request'"  style="border: none">
                <ul  style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled"   class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" style="border: none">
                  <strong  class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"  (click)="c.value.isCollapsedContent =!c.value.isCollapsedContent">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign"  (click)=" toggleSign(sign)"  ></span>{{c.key}}
                  </strong>
                  <li  class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="c.value.isCollapsedContent" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                    <table id="user" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style = "overflow: hidden;" width="100%" >
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                       <th>Field</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr *ngFor="let d of c.value | keys" class="list-group-item-info">

                        <td nowrap=" ">{{d.value.Field}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.value.length}}</td>
                        <td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px; white-space:normal">{{d.value.value}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="c.key == 'response'">
                <ul style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled"   class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" style="border: none">
                  <strong  class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"  (click)="c.value.isCollapsedContent =!c.value.isCollapsedContent"  (click)=" toggleSign(sign)" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign" ></span>{{c.key}}
                  </strong>
                  <li  class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="c.value.isCollapsedContent" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                    <table datatable="ng" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Field</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr *ngFor="let d of c.value | keys" class="list-group-item-info">
                        <td>{{d.value.Field}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.value.length}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.value.value}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and component is as below

```
import { NgModule,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AcquirerService} from '../services/acquirer.service'
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Collapse} from './collapse.component';



@Component({

  selector : 'acquirer-message',
  templateUrl: '../templates/acquirer.component.html',
//  template : '<parent-view [txn] = "acquirer_response"></parent-view>' ,

  providers :[AcquirerService]
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Collapse]
})
export class AcquirerComponent implements  OnInit {

  public isCollapsedContent:boolean = false;

  acquirer_response : any[];

  constructor(private _acquirerService:AcquirerService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._acquirerService.getAcquirer()
      .subscribe(resAcquirerData => {

        this.acquirer_response = resAcquirerData.transactions

        console.log(this.acquirer_response);
        // console.log(this.acquirer_response.transactions);
    });


  }

  sign = 'plus';  // or minus if you want that first

  toggleSign(value :string) {
    this.sign = value;
    if(this.sign == 'plus') {
      this.sign = 'minus';
    } else {
      this.sign = 'plus';
    }
  }


}

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value) {
    let keys:any = [];
    for (let key in value) {

      keys.push( {key: key, value: value[key]} );
      console.log("value of key :"+key ,"value :"+ value);
    }
    return keys;

  }

}
```

The outcome is as expected nice tree view as below

```
 Transaction ref : 321916010424
     request
     response
 Transaction ref : 000463000046
     request
     response
```

Now i would like to implement search/filter to the above say in my search box if i type 321916010424 it should display the record (the matching record as below )

```
Transaction ref : 321916010424
         request
         response
```

I understand it has to be done using pipes but don't know how to implement or what approach i should take , should i be able to use the existing pipe which is in the component if so how it can be achieved i am new to angular  2 or development. any help would be appreciated

for ref my json data looks like this

```
{
    "transactions": [{
        "Transaction ref : 321916010424": {
            "request": [{
                "Field": "DE-000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0100"
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-001",
                "length": "016",
                "value": "11110010 00111100 01000100 10000001 10001000 11100001 10000000 00001000                       00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 11000000 "
            }],
            "response": [{
                "Field": "DE-000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0110"
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-001",
                "length": "008",
                "value": "00110010 00111010 00000000 00000000 00001110 11000001 10000000 00000010 "
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-003",
                "length": "006",
                "value": "003000"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "Transaction ref : 000463000046": {
            "request": [{
                "Field": "DE-000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0100"
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-001",
                "length": "016",
                "value": "11110010 00111100 01000100 10000001 10101000 11100001 10000010 00001000                       00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 "
            }],
            "response": [{
                "Field": "DE-000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0110"
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-001",
                "length": "008",
                "value": "00110010 00111010 00000000 00000000 00001110 11000001 10000000 00000010 "
            }, {
                "Field": "DE-063",
                "length": "009",
                "value": "AMXHZGWJ7"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented as below 
created a search filter and pass the parameter if the parameter matches it will do the search 
below is my search pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';



@Pipe({name: 'Searchkeys'})
export class AcquirerTxnSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items, args:string) {

    let ans:any = [];
    // console.log("iam herer "+items);
    let result:any = [];
    let kvalue:any = [];


    if (args !== undefined) {
       console.log("value of args in loop condition-->" + args)

      for (let k in items) {

        kvalue = items[k];

        for (let a in kvalue) {
          if (a.substr(18).startsWith(args)) {
            ans.push({key: k, value: items[k]});

           console.log("mathced txn ==>" + ans)
            result = ans;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    else {

      console.log("value of args no undefined--->" + args);
      for (let k in items) {


        console.log("value of a --->"+ k)
        ans.push({key: k, value: items[k]});

        result = ans;

      }
    }


    return result;

  }

}
```

my another pipe which will load all the details

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class AcquirerTxnPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value) {
    let keys:any = [];
    for (let key in value) {

      keys.push( {key: key, value: value[key]} );
      console.log("value of key :"+key ,"value :"+ value);
    }
    return keys;

  }

}
```

so in HTML i called the search pipe to filter the record of interest , if there is an input in the search box if matches then select the record and pass it to the normal pipe to load the rest of the data below is the html

```
<div id="search-component">
  <h4>Transaction Search</h4>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" [(ngModel)]="queryString"  placeholder="Search to type" />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <div>
    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled" xmlns:list-style-type="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <li *ngFor="let t of searchacquirer_response | Searchkeys :queryString ">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"  class="list-group" >
          <li *ngFor="let b of t.value | keys" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" style ="list-style-type: none" >
              <strong (click)="t.isCollapsedContent =!t.isCollapsedContent" (click)=" toggleSign(sign)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign"></span> {{b.key}}</strong>
              <div *ngIf="t.isCollapsedContent">
                <li *ngFor="let c of b.value | keys ">
                  <div *ngIf="c.key == 'request'"  style="border: none">
                    <ul  style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled"   class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" style="border: none">
                      <strong  class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"  (click)="c.value.isCollapsedContent =!c.value.isCollapsedContent">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign"  (click)=" toggleSign(sign)"  ></span>{{c.key}}
                      </strong>
                      <li  class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="c.value.isCollapsedContent" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                        <table id="user" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style = "overflow: hidden;" width="100%" >
                          <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Field</th>
                            <th>Length</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tr *ngFor="let d of c.value | keys" class="list-group-item-info">

                            <td nowrap=" ">{{d.value.Field}}</td>
                            <td>{{d.value.length}}</td>
                            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px; white-space:normal">{{d.value.value}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="c.key == 'response'">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="list-unstyled"   class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" style="border: none">
                      <strong  class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"  (click)="c.value.isCollapsedContent =!c.value.isCollapsedContent"  (click)=" toggleSign(sign)" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{sign}}-sign" ></span>{{c.key}}
                      </strong>
                      <li  class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="c.value.isCollapsedContent" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                        <table datatable="ng" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                          <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Field</th>
                            <th>Length</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tr *ngFor="let d of c.value | keys" class="list-group-item-info">
                            <td nowrap=" ">{{d.value.Field}}</td>
                            <td>{{d.value.length}}</td>
                            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px; white-space:normal">{{d.value.value}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```